# Vertically center text in DIV

Tags: html, css

I have this HTML/CSS snippet:

```css
.matrix-right-letter-container {
 font-size: 48px;
}


.matrix-place {
 display: inline-block;
 vertical-align: top;
 margin: 10px;
}

.matrix-input {
 height: 50px;
 width: 50px;
 margin: 3px;
 vertical-align: bottom;
}
```

```html
<div class="matrix-line-container">
  <div id="matrix-c-place" class="matrix-place bracketed">
    CONTENT<br>CONTENT<br>CONTENT<br>CONTENT<br>CONTENT<br>CONTENT<br>CONTENT<br>
  </div>
  <div id="matrix-a-place" class="matrix-place bracketed">
    CONTENT<br>CONTENT<br>CONTENT<br>CONTENT<br>CONTENT<br>CONTENT<br>CONTENT<br>
  </div>
  <span class="matrix-right-letter-container">A</span>
</div>
```

I need to center letter **A** vertically in `matrix-line-container`. But adding `vertical-align: middle` to `.matrix-right-letter-container` doesn't help. How can I do it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to vertically center a div for all browsers?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/396145/how-to-vertically-center-a-div-for-all-browsers)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is two ways you can do this atleast. Ofcourse the CSS way or using some JS.

**option 1: CSS**

now you can give the parent container of your span text a `display:table` property and the element you want to vertical align itself a `display:table-cell` property and align it top, middle bottom etc.

Code snippet here:

```css
.matrix-line-container {
  background: grey;
  display: table;  /* See what I did here? */
}
.matrix-right-letter-container {
  font-size: 48px;
  background: cyan;
  display: table-cell;  /* And also here*/
  vertical-align: middle;  /* And here*/
}
.matrix-place {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  margin: 10px;
  background: pink;
}
.matrix-input {
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  margin: 3px;
  vertical-align: bottom;
}
```

```html
<div class="matrix-line-container">
  <div id="matrix-c-place" class="matrix-place bracketed">CONTENT
    <br/>CONTENT
    <br/>CONTENT
    <br/>CONTENT
    <br/>CONTENT
    <br/>CONTENT
    <br/>CONTENT
    <br/>
  </div>
  <div id="matrix-a-place" class="matrix-place bracketed">CONTENT
    <br/>CONTENT
    <br/>CONTENT
    <br/>CONTENT
    <br/>CONTENT
    <br/>CONTENT
    <br/>CONTENT
    <br/>
  </div> <span class="matrix-right-letter-container">A</span>

</div>
```

Now the second option,

**Option 2 : some JS** ( not really recommended but if you want to get fancy then , i guess)

In this option you just want to find the height of the height of the parent div element ( I have used jQuery, just because i like it, thats it, makes my typing easier. Now you have secondary options of just `height()` or `innerHeight()` or `outerHeight()`. Use it whatever you like according to user specific case). Once you have the height of the parent div element then just apply that height to your `span` element as `line-height` property and Voila! there you have it!

Now the code snippet for the second funky option,

```js
// Obviously I added some script - What else did you think I was gonna do?!!

var divht = $('.matrix-line-container').innerHeight() + 'px'; /* DO NOT forget to add that little 'px' to the end or else it wont work! */
$('.matrix-right-letter-container').css("line-height", divht);
```

```css
.matrix-line-container {
  background: grey;
}
.matrix-right-letter-container {
  font-size: 48px;
  background: cyan;
}
.matrix-place {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  margin: 10px;
  background: pink;
}
.matrix-input {
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  margin: 3px;
  vertical-align: bottom;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="matrix-line-container">
  <div id="matrix-c-place" class="matrix-place bracketed">CONTENT
    <br/>CONTENT
    <br/>CONTENT
    <br/>CONTENT
    <br/>CONTENT
    <br/>CONTENT
    <br/>CONTENT
    <br/>
  </div>
  <div id="matrix-a-place" class="matrix-place bracketed">CONTENT
    <br/>CONTENT
    <br/>CONTENT
    <br/>CONTENT
    <br/>CONTENT
    <br/>CONTENT
    <br/>CONTENT
    <br/>
  </div> <span class="matrix-right-letter-container">A</span>

</div>
```

Hope this has given you something to think about ;)

Hope this helps and **Happy coding**

Comment: Oh, thank you! It works! But could you describe browser's logic if it finds `block`, `inline-block` and `table-cell` mixed in `table`? And why does it work like I need?

Answer (score 1):

You should `vertical-align: middle` all inline-blocks in order to vertically align all of them relative to each other

```css
.matrix-right-letter-container {
 font-size: 48px;
}


.matrix-place {
 display: inline-block;
 vertical-align: middle;
 margin: 10px;
}

.matrix-input {
 height: 50px;
 width: 50px;
 margin: 3px;
 vertical-align: bottom;
}
```

```html
<div class="matrix-line-container">
  <div id="matrix-c-place" class="matrix-place bracketed">
    CONTENT<br>CONTENT<br>CONTENT<br>CONTENT<br>CONTENT<br>CONTENT<br>CONTENT<br>
  </div>
  <div id="matrix-a-place" class="matrix-place bracketed">
    CONTENT<br>CONTENT<br>CONTENT<br>CONTENT<br>CONTENT<br>CONTENT<br>CONTENT<br>
  </div>
  <span class="matrix-right-letter-container">A</span>
</div>
```